# Convert query into using EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I write a query to find some records ...

```
select account_num, mob_tele_feat_uid, mob_tele_feat, done
from LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd1
where (mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null)
   or (mob_tele_feat is not null and mob_tele_feat_uid is null);
```

data in table --

```
4579214598412   223344  {sw_dcf=Gold}|{sw_dcf_active_voice_bsg=Silver}|{sw_cfb=bronze}|{sw_c=bronze}    S
4579214598412   223344                                                                                  S
     null       null    null                                                                            P
```

Output of first query is ---

```
4579214598412   223344  null    S
```

I want to use this query in update statement using exists like

```
update load_mobile_data lmd
  set done = 'P'
where exists
  (select account_num, mob_tele_feat_uid, mob_tele_feat, done
   from LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd1
   where (mob_tele_feat is not null and mob_tele_feat_uid is null)
      or (mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null)
     and lmd.account_num = lmd1.account_num
     and lmd.mob_tele_feat = lmd.MOB_TELE_FEAT
     and lmd.MOB_TELE_FEAT_UID = lmd.MOB_TELE_FEAT_UID);
```

I want to mark DONE column = P  in LOAD_MOBILE_DATA  where either mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null or mob_tele_feat_uid is null but mob_tele_feat is not null

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to mark the done column of load_mobile_data table as 'P' if mob_tele_feat is not present in table but mob_tele_feat_uid is present or if mob_tele_feat present but mob_tele_feat_uid is not present

Comment: What's wrong with the query you posted?

Comment: it gives me one record where no criteria matches i.e. it gives me the row where mob_tele_feat is present and mob_tele_feat_uid is also present

Answer (score 1):

You overengineered it.  If this query returns the correct records:

```
select account_num, mob_tele_feat_uid, mob_tele_feat, done
from LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd1
where (mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null)
   or (mob_tele_feat is not null and mob_tele_feat_uid is null);
```

Then simply change this:

```
select account_num, mob_tele_feat_uid, mob_tele_feat, done
from LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd1
```

to this:

```
update load_mobile_data
set done = 'P'
```

Comment: Hehehe :) yeah you are right you see i am doing these validation and i was mostly using exists operator for validation as the data going to be big in size and now you see ....  By the way Thanks i need some discussion :)

Comment: However now i have raised this question can we do this scenario using exists operator ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this CTE update** 
Please modify Join condition as per you matching column

```
    WITH temptable AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM load_mobile_data WHERE 
        (mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null) 
        OR (mob_tele_feat is not null and mob_tele_feat_uid is null)
    )
    UPDATE a SET a.done='P' FROM load_mobile_data a JOIN temptable b 
    ON a.account_num=b.account_num
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ... just update you query.

```
UPDATE (
    select *
    from LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd1
    where (mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null)
       or (mob_tele_feat is not null and mob_tele_feat_uid is null)
)
SET done = 'P'
```

---

If you really want to use EXISTS operator, then you need to use a primary key column that uniquely identifies each row in the table:

```
UPDATE  LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd1
SET done = 'P'
WHERE EXISTS (
        select *
        from LOAD_MOBILE_DATA lmd2
        where 
           lmd1.id = lmd2.id
           AND
           (
             (mob_tele_feat is null and mob_tele_feat_uid is not null)
             or (mob_tele_feat is not null and mob_tele_feat_uid is null)
           )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Kordirko